# Is FullCalendar the right thing to use to make a scheduling app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar, schedule

I'm trying to make a web app that allows (student) users to see all possible class schedules that they can have.  Right now, I've got a list of classes that fit certain constraints (users desired classes).  I want to create all possible schedules that can be made with combinations of these classes.  It seems like FullCalendar might be what I want to display these schedules (just in a week view or something) but i'm not sure if I can make FullCalendar just display a possible schedule and then allow the user to click through the possible schedules without assigning all the classes dates or something on the back end.

In a nutshell:
Is FullCalendar what I want to use for this? Or is there something else better suited to my goal?

Below is the code I have so far (still figuring out how to get lists of all possible schedules from this list)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 id="search_results"></h2>

<div id="morning_results_container">
    <h5>Morning Courses</h5>
    <ul id="morning_results_list">
    </ul>    
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {


$.getJSON("http://vazzak2.ci.northwestern.edu/courses/?term=4540&subject=EECS", function(result) {
    var earlyCourses = [];

    $(result).each(function (index, item) {
        $('#search_results').text((index+1) + " total courses");

        if (item.start_time > '10:00:00') {
            if (item.meeting_days === 'We'){
            console.log(item);
                $('#morning_results_list').append('<li>' +   item.title + '</li>');
            }
        }        
    });
});


    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="resultarea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any experiential advice you can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you can achieve what you like to do with jquery [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) plugin you are using. I'm not sure whether there is a better plugin for your purpose. FullCalendar pretty much provides a very good user interface for a interactive calendar for any type of web app.

However it's up to you to implement what it should do in your web app based on the UI interactions of a user. Could you provide a example of a JSON output with all the schedules? As I understood your question, maybe you can allow the user to select a schedule from a drop-down list and then show the classes in the calendar for a selected schedule.

**[Update]**

```
function load_all_classes()
{
    $.getJSON("http://vazzak2.ci.northwestern.edu/courses/?term=4540&subject=EECS", function(data) {
       window.all_classes = data;

    });
}

function update_calendar(classes)
{
    //update calendar to display the given classes
}

function get_classes_before_10_am()
{
    var results = [];

    $(window.all_classes).each(function (index, the_class) {

       if (the_class.start_time <= '10:00:00') {
         results.push(the_class);                            
       }    

    });

    return results;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

   load_all_classes();

   $('#select_schedule').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val = 'Before 10 am')
        {
           update_calendar(get_classes_before_10_am());
        }
        else if ($(this).val = 'After 10 am')
        {
          update_calendar(get_classes_after_10_am());
        }
        //...etc
    }); 

 });
```

Comment: Thanks @Panda86. Having a drop-down would be great. I want the user to be able to pick their classes with some filters (not before 10am etc) and then be able to look through (via drop-down or clicking through etc) all possible schedules that they could have with those resulting classes. I'm still trying to figure out how to make all possible schedules from just the list of classes. Any thoughts you have there would be great.